# "Extra \else" error when my macro is used in certain locations

Tags: expansion

I am working on a group theory document in which I need to mention mathematical sets a lot. I have a working macro which expands `\fn f:D->R` to `f:\set D \mapsto \set R`, and I have replaced `\in` such that `x \in Z` expands to `x \oldin \set Z` (\oldin has already been \let to \in).

Now I am struggling with the definition of `\set`. The aim is to easily capture the difference between - "my" sets such as D (the domain) and R (the range) - and "standard" sets such as Z (the integers) and R (the reals). (Notice that 'R' appears in both contexts.)

To do this (as a complete TeX noob), I thought I could perhaps use `\set D` and `\set R` for set names that I want as `\mathcal` and `\set ZZ` and `\set RR` for `\mathbb`.

This works:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\def\set#1#2{\ifx#1#2\mathbb #1\else\mathcal #1 #2\fi}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
A \mapsto \set A BB \mapsto \set BB\\
C \mapsto \set C\\
DD \mapsto \set DD\\
\end{align}

\(\set Z\)
\(\set YY\)
\end{document}
```

and produces:

[image: working sample]

(The idea is that in the case of `\set RR`, #1 and #2 are both 'R', so expand to `\mathbb R` and in the case of `\set R`, #1 will be 'R', but #2 will be the next token (which \set shouldn't do anything with) so expand to `\mathcal R` and "re-emit" #2.)

But when I try:

```
\(\set Z \set ZZ\)
```

I get the following error:

```
! Extra \else.
\set #1#2->\ifx #1#2\mathbb #1\else
                                    \mathcal #1 #2\fi
l.17 \(\set Z \set Z
                    Z\)
```

If I am going about this completely the wrong way, please let me know a better solution (I would like to learn the "proper" way to TeX), but regardless, I would still like to understand what I am doing wrong here and how to fix it.

---

*Edited to add context*

I am working my way through a text on group theory, and keeping my personal summary/notes for later reference in an emacs org-mode file. An excerpt from my file used to look like this:

```
* Group Theory
  ** Functions
    - A function \(f:\mathcal{D}\mapsto\mathcal{R}\) maps /every/ \(x\in\mathcal{D}\) to /exactly one/ \(y\in\mathcal{R}\).
```

Which, although it renders to PDF beautifully, is difficult for me to read as plain text. It now looks like this:

```
* Group Theory
  ** Functions
    - A function \(\fn f:D->R\) maps /every/ \(x \in D\) to /exactly one/ \(y \in R\).
```

Comment: you can't do that easily. You'd have to either be sure that `#2` is a single token (you don't know this) or to make things non-expandable, because what you basically want is `\expandafter#2\fi`, but this will fail miserably if `#2` is not a single token.

Comment: However, this whole things smells to me, and your approach is bad from all points of view (not even "almost all"). Why can't you define `\setZZ`, `\setNN`, `\setA` etc.? It differs from your current code by **one space** in each case and by couple lines of header code. What you gain is code clarity -- everybody can easily see what `\setZZ` does if you define `\newcommand*\setZZ{\mathbb{Z}}`. Not so quite with your crazy definition of `\set`.

Comment: Third thing: Introducing markup into LaTeX is a straight way to hell. If I ever got (as a journal typesetter) a code that contains your `\fn`, I would 99% sure call you names. Also, how is _anybody_ suppose to predict what the code does in critical situations, like `\fn f^{-1} : \langle0,1)\cup\set ZZ -> (3,\frac{7}{2}\rangle` ? For instance, will your code produce the correct spacing around the opening parenthesis?

Comment: @yo' - Thanks for your input. I've edited my post to add context and an example of what I'm trying to accomplish. Regarding why I don't define \setZZ etc - this is because \set is used by \fn and my \in, so I was trying to keep it generic. Henri's fix works great for me, but I do hear what you're saying, and I'll certainly not attempt this sort of thing for anything other than personal files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't remove the following token by swallowing it as an argument.  Use `\futurelet` instead and remove the token only if they are the same.  There is a really convenient LaTeX wrapped around it called `\@ifnextchar`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\makeatletter
\def\set#1{%
  \@ifnextchar{#1}{\mathbb{#1}\@gobble}{\mathcal{#1}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\(\set Z \set ZZ\)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 very nice! Still, I stand by my comment about this all being a conceptual mess.

Comment: @yo' I agree.  Better use `\newcommand*\ZZ{\mathbb{Z}}`.

Comment: Thanks, @Henri. That not only solved my problem but has also given me a good understanding of what went wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Your error is

```
#2\fi}
```

as when `#2` is `\set` this is

```
... \set\fi...
```

so on the next invocation of `\set` `#1`  is `\fi` and things go bad.

It is almost always better to expand the `\fi` (to nothing) before executing the true or false branches, if you do that then the token after the re-inserted `#2` will be the token from the original source.

This is why you usually see `\expandafter` in `\if...` examples you see posted.

The code below does what you want but you shouldn't use it, it will give a nasty error from `\set R}` as the `}` will prevent it picking up a second argument, and it breaks the latex syntax no command should have variable number of mandatory arguments. `\set RR, \set R` would be better marked up as `\seta R, \setb R` with simple definitions of `\seta` and `\setb` as `\mathbb` and `\mathcal`

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\makeatletter

\def\set#1#2{%
\ifx#1#2\mathbb{#1}\expandafter\@gobble\else
\mathcal{#1}\expandafter\@firstofone\fi
{#2}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
A \mapsto \set A BB \mapsto \set BB\\
C \mapsto \set C\\
DD \mapsto \set DD\\
\end{align}

\(\set Z\)
\(\set YY\)
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want your definition working, please add an empty argument:

```
%\documentclass{article}
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\def\set#1#2{\ifx#1#2\mathbb #1\else\mathcal #1 #2\fi}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
A \mapsto \set A BB \mapsto \set BB\\
C \mapsto \set C\\
DD \mapsto \set DD\\
\end{align}

\(\set Z\)
\(\set YY\)

$\set Z{} \set ZZ$
\end{document}
```

A  better solution you have in the other answer.